# Single, horizontally scrollable line in a pre?

Tags: html, css

I have a pretty simple bit of HTML which I'm attempting (and failing miserably at) getting formatted properly. I essentially have the following element:

```
<pre>http://myserver.com:9000/something/REQUEST/124125125125?username=username&password=password</pre>
```

I essentially need to mimic what you're seeing above me in a pre. I need to have a single line of text show up as a single line of text within a pre with a horizontal scroll if necessary.

All attempts to do this so far have failed. The `<pre>` exists as a child of a `<td>`:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Behold some incredible, glowy sample text, and then a URL:
                <pre>...</pre>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackOverflow uses

```
overflow: auto;
width: auto;
```

With an explicit width (730px) on a parent container of the `<pre>`